# Sending email from corporate email to mail server deployed on intranet

Tags: email, cloud, intranet

I have deployed mail server in the intranet. Whenever I try to send email from my corporate email server, the mail does not get delivered. Gives error like IP not found. 
But when I deploy mail server on DMZ (cloud), it works.

So when both corporate email server & my test mail server are in same intranet, why the email gets bounced?

Comment: Belongs on http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

Check DNS MX record for the domain from the email address used in To: field.
The sending server will try to deliver your email to one of the MX-servers first.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should run a test on your email server to make sure you don't have any config problems.  You could try http://www.emailsecuritygrader.com it's a free online tool that I think works well. It runs a series of security tests on all mail servers defined in the MX record for your domain and will give you recommendations on the problems found.